# Permanent redirection from a sub-directory to main directory

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard, redirect

I would like to permanently redirect all like below:

```
www.website.com/en/xyz
```

to

```
www.website.com/xyz
```

'xyz' can be anything.

Please note:

1. This should apply for www, HTTP, https, etc
2. Wild Card * should work.

I don't want `www.website.com/en/xyz` to be redirected to `www.website.com`

It should be www.website.com/en/xyz to `www.website.com/xyz`

The xyz is important.

The /en folder does not exist in my website anymore so I need this redirection.
P.S I found many places in stack overflow giving answers for this but I am unsure what to apply for permanent redirection with my queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```